# TIKZ MODULO inside of FOR LOOP

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, pgfmath

I am doing something simple with tikz, but code keeps not compiling. I would like to have something like this:

```
\foreach \x in {0,...,4}
    \foreach \y in {0,...,4} 

   \ifthenelse{mod(\x, 2)=0 \AND \y=3 }{   \node (\x\y) at (1.5*\x,1.5*\y) { $e^{l+1}_{1}$ };} {};
```

What is correct tikz syntax for this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Untested, but `\pgfmathifthenelse{and(mod(\x,2)=0,\y=3)}{...}{}` should do it. If not, please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), which shows your problem

Comment: Why are you shouting?

Comment: @Mike I tried `\pgfmathifthenelse{mod(\i,2)=0}{\node at (\i,\i) {$A$}}{\node at (\i,\i) {$B$}}`, but it appears to always just write $B$. That is, it always takes the second branch of the ifthenelse.